# Bootstrap caption position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/gh4Lur4b/2/

It's a bootstrap carousel with caption on each slide.

I'd like to change the position of the caption so it is left aligned to the red block below that is a bootstrap container block. I can position it with px or % but looks out of place at big pr small screen sizes.

I'd also like to have the text inline and have a black background. In the example I have done it by fixed the width of the container which won't work because I don't know how much text that will be.

```
        .block{
            background: red;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .carousel-caption{
            font-size: 3em;
            left: 10%;
            text-align: left;
            background: black;
            color: white;
            display: inline;
            width: 200px;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.To align left edge with the red block, you could add `left: 0;` to your class `.carousel-caption`. So the caption will be positioned to the left edge.

2.For the size of the caption box. No need to set the size in fix pixel. The reason why there is a strange width for this box is. The CSS code in Bootstrap has already set a rule `right:15%;`. That makes the right side of this box stick to the 15% of the right edge. It automatically drag the box's right edge. Thus, let remove this rule by add `right:auto;` to your `.carousel-caption`, and remember to remove the `width:200px;`  .

Comment: setting it to `left: 0;` will align it to the edge of the screen not in line with the red block. I'll have to position if with px and then change it with media queries

Answer (score 0):

You can override it by putting styles `width: 46%;` and `margin-left: -153px;` into `.carousel-caption` class.

Comment: inside this class  .carousel-caption